# How to link the View and the ViewModel and where to create them

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

I have written a phone app using an MVVM framework.  It came together okay - every page (view) on the phone has its own ViewModel and code within each ViewModel went away to the dataservice and retrieved appropriate data.

So I had a page showing an Agenda of upcoming items and its ViewModel  retrieved a collection of events and within the XAML I bound a Listbox to this collection.
Similarly I had another page showing a OneOff Events and again, within its VM I  called the data service to get a collection of data back and  that was bound to a listbox within its view.

Not sure how good an implementation of MVVM this is, but, I ended up moving to a different database - and it was very easy to implement another dataservice without touching anything else and it all worked great.

Ok - so now I am looking to rework this app into a Windows Store app.  I now have a main page that will show a combination of data that on the phone was shown on individual pages.
Hypothetically, assume that the Agenda items and One Off Events mentioned above are now appearing on the same main page (so much more room to show stuff)

Just struggling with what this means for ViewModel(s).   If the MainPage can only work with one ViewModel, do I end up with one huge ViewModel that includes all the functionality that was in multiple VM's before.

Or should the Main ViewModel have within it collections of ViewModels.  From looking around this seems to be the way it could be done, but, if so where are the ViewModels created?
It seems quite a fundamental shift from what I have done previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set different ViewModels as the binding context for different parts of your page. You can use the Locator pattern (one locator object with ViewModel properties) or Dependency Injection to keep the construction of things manageable.

Great sample code and slides by Gill Cleeren that discuss and show how the [Contoso Cookbook sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj819238.aspx) can be set up alternatively using MVVM and a ViewModelLocator class can be found [here](http://www.snowball.be/2013/03/08/Slides+And+Demos+For+My+Advanced+MVVM+Cookbook+Session.aspx). The talk itself is on [channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2013-the-Netherlands/MVVM-and-Windows-8).

From these slides:

> Data binding is the glue but...
>
> A view needs to “find” its ViewModel
>
> - ViewModel is the DataContext
>
> Can be static or dynamic
>
> - Static: View creates ViewModel and sets it as DataContext
> - Dynamic: at runtime, View selects its ViewModel or vice-versa
>
>   2 options:
>
>   - View-First: ViewModel gets created because View is created
>   - ViewModel-First: ViewModel is created and View gets selected